# What is different the two font?

Tags: java, fonts, itext

When i print **TextRenderInfo.getFont().getPostscriptFontName()** in two pdf file, it will be printed **AAAAAD+SourceHanSansCN-Normal** and **BIISMY+SourceHanSansCN-Normal**.

I known **SourceHanSansCN-Normal** is format of FontName-FontScript, but what is AAAAAD ? Is not like font family.

Example Code:

```
public class CheckPdfAllFontTest implements TextExtractionStrategy {

    public static final String SRC = "ownTestFile.pdf";

    @Override
    public String getResultantText() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() {

    }

    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo textRenderInfo) {
        String x = textRenderInfo.getFont().getPostscriptFontName();
        String text = textRenderInfo.getText();
        System.out.println(text + "=====" + x);
    }

    @Override
    public void endTextBlock() {

    }

    @Override
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo imageRenderInfo) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        new CheckPdfAllFontTest().parse(SRC);
    }

    public void parse(String filename) throws IOException, IOException {
        int pageNumber = 1;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
        System.out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber, new CheckPdfAllFontTest()));
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Itext pdf version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The two pdf is exported with "embed font" and "not embed font" setting from a Power Point File.

- "AAAAAD+SourceHanSansCN-Normal" from "embed font" pdf file.
- "BIISMY+SourceHanSansCN-Normal" from "not embed font" pdf file.

I am collecting the fonts used in pdf, but I found that there are fonts in this format. I don’t know what is before the ‘+’. What is its definition?

Comment: @KJ thx for you answer, there have a way to check local fonts subset ? I need to avoid 'Missing Character' when system rendering. Wanna go to confirm local font contain all fonts used in a pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PDF specification:

> #### 9.9.2 Font subsets
>
> PDF documents may include subsets of PDF fonts whose **Subtype** is *Type1*, *TrueType* or *OpenType*. The font and font descriptor that describe a font subset are slightly different from those of ordinary fonts. These differences allow a PDF processor to recognise font subsets and to merge documents containing different subsets of the same font. (For more information on font descriptors, see 9.8, "Font descriptors".)
>
> For a font subset, the PostScript name of the font, that is, the value of the font’s **BaseFont** entry and the font descriptor’s **FontName** entry, shall begin with a tag followed by a plus sign (+) followed by the PostScript name of the font from which the subset was created. The tag shall consist of exactly six uppercase letters; the choice of letters is arbitrary, but different subsets of the same font in the same PDF file shall have different tags. The glyph name **.notdef** shall be defined in the font subset.
>
> NOTE It is recommended that PDF processors treat multiple subset fonts as completely independent entities, even if they appear to have been created from the same original font.
>
> EXAMPLE EOODIA+Poetica is the name of a subset of Poetica®, a Type 1 font.

*(ISO 32000-2)*

Thus, AAAAAD+SourceHanSansCN-Normal and BIISMY+SourceHanSansCN-Normal most likely are different subsets of the same source font.